# DigitalOcean - How to deploy two WordPress installations on the same droplet?

Tags: wordpress, apache, lamp, digital-ocean, ubuntu-server

I have two domains, www.example.com and blah.example.com. I want to map them to two different WordPress installations on the same DigitalOcean server running Ubuntu 16.04. I tried following a tutorial here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps.

But that didn't work or maybe I didn't execute properly. Can someone please guide me with the essential steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vijay Kumar both domains should be declared in the network tab as cnames to your server on the droplet admin panel.

```
cname: www
cname: blah
```

After that you should check you **conf** files in apache's **sites-available** folder to see if they point to the right directories. You should have one for every domain.

Let me know if you this is not working for you.